# What is the name of the Subversion server process on MacOS?

Tags: ssh, daemons, subversion

I'm running a Subversion server on MacOS. My remote IDEs connect no problem (*using ssh tunneling*). But, I can't figure-out the process name of the Subversion server.

It is so easy:

```
$ mkdir svnroot
$ svnadmin create /Users/johndoe/dev/svnroot
$ svn checkout svn+ssh://jdoe-macbook/Users/johndoe/dev/svnroot
```

But I go looking for the server as such:

```
$ sudo ps -eal | grep svn
```

doesn't return anything. And none of the processes listed in *Activity Manager* jump out at me as anything that might be a Subversion server.

To get ssh tunneling to work, I had to make adjustments to *System Preferences --> Sharing*. The ssh server is involved first. But then, what is ssh connecting to to manage the Subversion repositories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you [tunnel over `ssh`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshauth) using `svn checkout svn+ssh://..`, the `svn` client is actually running `svnserve -q -t` for the duration of each `ssh` connection and then shutting down `svnserve` when the connection closes.

If you want to see this in action, try opening two Terminal sessions:

- In Terminal session 1, run an `svn` command with the `svn+ssh://` protocol. Assuming you don't have any `ssh` identities saved in your `ssh-agent`, this should pause waiting for you to enter your password: `svn checkout svn+ssh://localhost/Users/johndoe/dev/svnroot`.
- Now switch to Terminal session 2. You should be able to find at least one `svnserve` process open via:  `ps -ef | grep svnserve`.

  For example, you should see a matching process similar to:

  `501 12869 12856   0  6:06pm ttys001    0:00.03 ssh -q -- localhost svnserve -t`
- If you return to Terminal session 1 and either complete or abort the `svn` command, the associated `ssh` session and `svnserve` process will quit.

Note: if you are connecting to a local repository you can use the `file://` protocol instead of tunnelling back into localhost via `ssh`.

For example:  `svn checkout file://localhost/Users/johndoe/dev/svnroot`